# Run Protractor Tests in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, protractor

I have been able to write tests using protractor in VS2013, however, when I open my "Test Explorer" tab and right click on the test I want to run it fails within seconds.  I'm wondering if it is not possible to run protractor tests this way and if they can only be run from the cmd.

I have checked out the links left on other questions on this site and none of them have fixed the issue I am running into.

Answer (score 7):

Yes that is possible to Run the Protractor Tests in Visual Studio.

To run the Tests, you need to create a Node.Js Console application (Get template online) and create the  project.

Here are the Steps:

- Install Node.js
- Install Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
- Configure JDK
- Create a Node.js Console Application and install Protractor

  npm install protractor --save-dev
- Update selenium standalone server
  .bin\webdriver-manager update
- Start selenium standalone server
  .bin\webdriver-manager start
- Run test specs
  .bin\protractor protractor.conf.js

To get the tests in the Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2013, you need to get the Chutzpah Test Adapter which is a extension of visual studio.

you can either go to https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe and download or go to Tools => extension and updates => search for this tool.

Once you have installed, you can run the tests directly from visual studio.

Comment: I'm using the Chutzpah Test Adapter but my tests all fail because of `ReferenceError: can't find variable browser`. Any ideas?

Comment: might be you are missing some steps.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Can't seem to find any solution.

Comment: please follow the steps and also update latest packages